# SearchDelegate on query change

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I created this very simple class extending SearchDelegate to use it as search bar:

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String>{
  
  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {query = '';},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        onPressed: (){close(context, '');},
        icon: AnimatedIcon(
          progress: transitionAnimation,
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    //TODO show some results based on the selection
    return Scaffold();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final namesList = [];
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty ? [] : namesList;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: suggestionList[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: suggestionList[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

and it works but to make it a bit better I'd like to make a new query to my database everytime the user inserts/removes a letter to the text input (similarly to the the onChanged attribute of the TextField) but I can't find a way to do it.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the method anywhere inside the buildSuggestions Widget;

Comment: Can you make an example please?

Answer (score 0):

`buildSuggestions` is called every time the `query` value has changed, so you can pass a function and call it here.

```dart
void onChange () {
  // do stuff
}

showSearch(
  context: context,
  delegate: CustomSearchDelegate(onChange),
)
```

Then in your `SearchDelegate`:

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  final Function(String query) onChange;

  CustomerSearchDelegate(this.onChange);

  ...

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    onChange(query); // <-- here
    ...
  }
}
```